# Invert a power series

Tags: power-series

I am trying to invert (?) a power series. Let
$$y(x) = \sum_{k \geq 1} a_k x^k$$
I need to find the coefficients $b_k$ such that
$$x(y) = \sum_{k \geq 1} b_k y^k$$

For example, I have the following power series (assuming convergence)
$$x(z) = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{z^k}{k^n} \hspace{1cm} \text{n > 0}$$
and I want z(x)

Comment: The Inverse Function Theorem for derivatives should give you the first few coefficients, but that gets ugly fast.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html

Comment: Usually the sums are over $k\geq 1$. Especially your last one ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments!